# Python rstrip() (for tabs) not working as expected

Tags: python, string, strip

I was trying out the rstrip() function, but it doesn't work as expected.
For example, if I run this:

```
lines = ['tra\tla\tla\t\t\t\n', 'tri\tli\tli\t\t\t\n', 'tro\tlo\tlo\t\t\t\n']

for line in lines:
    line.rstrip('\t')

print lines
```

It returns

```
['tra\tla\tla\t\t\t\n', 'tri\tli\tli\t\t\t\n', 'tro\tlo\tlo\t\t\t\n']
```

whereas I want it to return:

```
['tra\tla\tla\n', 'tri\tli\tli\n', 'tro\tlo\tlo\n']
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Strings in python are immutable, which means that string functions *always* return the new string instead of modifying it in place.

Answer (score 4):

The function returns the *new*, stripped string, but you discard that return value.

Use a list comprehension instead to replace the whole `lines` list; you'll need to ignore the newlines at the end as well; the `.rstrip()` method won't ignore those for you.

```
lines = [line[:-1].rstrip('\t') + '\n' for line in lines]
```

Demo:

```
>>> lines = ['tra\tla\tla\t\t\t\n', 'tri\tli\tli\t\t\t\n', 'tro\tlo\tlo\t\t\t\n']
>>> [line[:-1].rstrip('\t') + '\n' for line in lines]
['tra\tla\tla\n', 'tri\tli\tli\n', 'tro\tlo\tlo\n']
```

Comment: Instead of stripping the last character with a slice you can use `rstrip('\t\n')` and remove them both at the same time, or just use `rstrip()` and get rid of blanks too.

Comment: @MarkRansom: since the output includes that newline too, I was presuming that it needed to be preserved. The biggest problem here is that the OP is assuming that strings are modified in-place.

Comment: But you're not preserving it, you're adding it back after the fact. Might as well strip it the easy way.

Comment: (And indeed some other newlines had to be preserved, so Martijn's solution worked best for the dataset that I had to strip.)